# ngspice simulation : random signal source

Tags: noise, simulation, ngspice, random

I'm new at the ngspice simulator and I don't understand this line of a Netlist that I found

```
Vn 1 n1 dc 0V ac 1mV trrandom(1 5us 0s 125m 0m)
```

if the random signal is only used in the transient simulation why did they keep the ac signal with an amplitude of 1mV ?

Comment: I don't understand the (Independent Sources for Voltage) and (dependent Sources for Voltage) part of your question. I think it has nothing to do with dependency. Hopefully, my answer clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just in the [manual](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice-manual.pdf)
:

> **4.1.8 Randomvoltagesource**
>   The TRRANDOM option yields statistically distributed voltage values, derived from the ngspice random number generator. These values **may be used in the transient simulation** directly within a circuit, e.g.  for generating a speciﬁc noise voltage, but especially they may be used  in the control of behavioral sources […] to simulate the circuit dependence on statistically varying device parameters. A Monte-Carlo simulation may thus be handled in a single simulation run.

You should read the line as follows:

```
Vn 1 n1 dc 0V ac 1mV trrandom(1 5us 0s 125m 0m) 
--
name of voltage source

Vn 1 n1 dc 0V ac 1mV trrandom(1 5us 0s 125m 0m) 
   ----
nodes the voltage source is connected to

Vn 1 n1 dc 0V ac 1mV trrandom(1 5us 0s 125m 0m) 
        -----
type and value of voltage source for transient analysis

Vn 1 n1 dc 0V ac 1mV trrandom(1 5us 0s 125m 0m) 
              ------
AC amplitude for ac analysis

Vn 1 n1 dc 0V ac 1mV trrandom(1 5us 0s 125m 0m) 
        +++++        --------------------------
adds statistically distributed voltage values to the DC of 0V (the +++ part)
```

According the specification of `TRRANDOM(TYPE TS <TD <PARAM1 <PARAM2>>>)` in your example

- the noise is uniformly distributed
- the duration of an individual voltage value is 5 us
- time delay parameter is not used
- the noise has an amplitude of 125mV
- the noise has an offset of 0mV

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications it helped me a lot, just to make sure I understood well, does it means that we generate an ac sinusoïdal signal (with an amplitude of 1mV) to which we will superimpose a random signal (a uniformly distributed noise with an amplitude of 125mV ? this kind of source is allowed only for transient or ac simulations .noise simulation doesn't work with it ?

Comment: @asssi transient analysis =/= AC analysis. ```trrandom``` only applies to transient analysis. If you want a sinusoidal signal, you should do something like ```Vn 1 n1 SINE 0mV 1mV 1kHz trrandom(1 5us 0s 125m 0m)```

Comment: As you noticed I left out the ```ac 1mV``` part, because it does not affect transient analysis

Comment: @asssi I'm not completely sure how the TS and TD work. You'd better make a noise source (like ```Vn 2 1 dc 0V trrandom(1 5us 0s 125m 0m)```) and check whether it satisfies and then put a SINE voltage source (like ```Vn 1 0 sine 0mV 1mV 1kHz```) in series.

Comment: I got it thank you it is not my purpose to have a sinusoidal signal to which we superimpose a random signal, now that I unserstood what you said and I have checked the rest of the netlist which contains two types of simulations             .tran 0.1m 5m 0m 1u
.ac dec 1000 1 10Meg